# How to write unit test of a void method which have multiple private method using junit Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to test a void method which have multiple private method , the approach I am taking is,
trying to test the public method which shall only , below is the public method

```
class Container{ 

public void checkAndUpdate(Service service, Actual actual){
 List<Address> addList = new ArrayList<>();
 for(Address addr: service.getAddress()){
  addList.add(addr);
}
somePrivateMethod(addList);
}
```

Test class

```
@Mock
Container container;

@Test
public void testCheckAndUpdate(){
 
List<Address> addList = Mockito.mock(List.class);
Service service = Mockito.mock(Service.class);
Actual actual = new Actual();
actual.setValue("TA");
service.setAddress(addList);

Mockito.verify(container).checkAndUpdate(service,actual);
```

I am getting the below exception

```
   "Actually there were zero interactions with the mock 
    wanted but not invoked
```

How to solve this issue

Comment: You have called a service method (setAddress), Mockito verify checks whether container's checkAndUpdate method was called. Who was supposed to invoke it?

Comment: The general idea is not ok, if you want to test Container.checkAndUpdate, you shouldn't mock the container at all

Comment: @leokom Can you edit my code

Comment: @leokom then how i will write the unit test ?container is the class where it is written

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify interaction with the private method (if you really want doing that), its visibility should be increased to package-private one.

Then the following approach may be used

```
class ContainerTest {
    @Test
    void testCheckAndUpdate() {

        List<Address> addList = new ArrayList<>();
        Service service = Mockito.mock(Service.class);
        Actual actual = new Actual();
        actual.setValue("TA");
        service.setAddress(addList);

        Container container = Mockito.spy(new Container());
        // call the public method
        container.checkAndUpdate(service, actual);

        // verify interaction with the package-private method
        Mockito.verify(container).somePrivateMethod(addList);
    }
}
```